# Convert Hex to Decimal from char array

Tags: c, hex, microcontroller, esp32

I have a CHAR buffer That contains some hex value
first of all i want to concatenate every 2 successive elements of the array then convert it to Decimal for example i have **recvbuf[i] = d** and **recvbuf[i+1] = 60** >>> **recvbuf[i] = d60** (hex value) >>> **recvbuf[i] =3424** (in decimal)

i started with this :

**recvbuf[i]=recvbuf[i]&recvbuf[i+1];**

can you help convert recvbuf[i] to Decimal value please

Comment: `recvbuf[i] = 0xd60` This is not possible. The array element does not magically change from `char` to `short` or any other type. You must provide a new variable to hold the combined value.

Comment: If you are dealing with hex values (numerical data), you should better use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` to store the values. Type `char` is mainly suitable to handle characters. Also I am not sure what conversion you want to do in that second step. Hex or decimal are only printable represenations of the same value. Please provide a sample code that shows what input data you have (data type and value) and what output (again type and value) you want to achieve.

Comment: There is no such thign as a hex value. Hex is a representation used when printing. Your `char` array contains binary. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your question lacks some information, I try to provide an answer for what I have understood.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define NUM_VALUES 5
int main(void)
{
  uint8_t input_data[NUM_VALUES * 2] = {1, 2, 0x0d, 0x60, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  uint16_t result_data[NUM_VALUES];

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VALUES; i++)
  {
    result_data[i] = (uint16_t)input_data[2*i] << 8 | input_data[2*i+1];
    printf("result[%d] = 0x%04x == %5u\n", i, result_data[i], result_data[i]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
~/tests$ ./test
result[0] = 0x0102 ==   258
result[1] = 0x0d60 ==  3424
result[2] = 0x0506 ==  1286
result[3] = 0x0708 ==  1800
result[4] = 0x090a ==  2314
```

As you can see, hex and decimal are only representation of the same value.